# C++ sorting an array in ascending order Printing

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Im trying to sort an array in ascending order and print it out and Im having trouble of where to put my cout in my code.

```
for (int k=0; k<ARRAY_SIZE; k++) {
    for (int l=1; l<ARRAY_SIZE-1; l++) {
        if(numbers[l] > numbers[k]) {
            temp = numbers[k];
            numbers[k] = numbers[l];
            numbers[l] = temp;
        }
        cout<<numbers[k];
    }    
}
```

Comment: Are you having trouble sorting or printing? Adjust your title or question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the actual `cout` and put it after the sorting loop, in a new loop

```
for(int k = 0 ; k < ARRAY_SIZE; ++k)
    cout << numbers[k] << " ";
```

Comment: I added that to my code and its causing my array to repeat

Comment: Make sure you put the loop outside. If the bubble sort works correctly, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the result of sorting you have to print the array in new for loop

Answer (score 0):

This is a program that finds the length of a number `n` and converts it to an array `arr` and sorts that array in ascending order.`(possible aptitude question)`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,i=0,j,num,temp,len=0,arr[10]={0};
    cin>>n;
    num=n;
while(n!=0)
    {
        len++;
        n/=10;
    }
    cout<<len<<endl;
    for ( i = len; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            arr[i] = num%10;
            num/=10;
    }
for(i=1;i<=len;i++)
    for(j=0;j<=len-i;j++)
{
    if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])
    {
        temp=arr[j];
        arr[j]=arr[j+1];
        arr[j+1]=temp;
    }
}
for(i=1;i<=len;i++)
{
    cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//array declaration
int arr[] = {1,2,5,8,4,3};
int n,i,j;
n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
int temp;

//print input elements
cout<<"Unsorted Array elements:"<<endl;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
if(arr[i] == arr[n - 1]){
    cout<<arr[i]<<"";
}else{
    cout<<arr[i]<<",";
}
cout<<endl;

//sorting - ASCENDING ORDER
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{       
    for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(arr[i]>arr[j])
        {
            temp  =arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[j];
            arr[j]=temp;
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
//print sorted array elements
cout<<"Sorted (Ascending Order) Array elements:"<<endl;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
if(arr[i] == arr[n - 1]){
    cout<<arr[i]<<"";
}else{
    cout<<arr[i]<<",";
}
    
cout<<endl; 


return 0;



}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should carefully review your code: `if(arr[i] == arr[n - 1])` is not what you want!

Comment: I think there is no problem in that cause it only getting the last element of array by printing it with no `,` @NorbertM

Comment: What about `if(i == n - 1)`, that would do the check for last element ;)